# Can't execute a main function in a jar after installing it

Tags: java, jar, jvm, classpath, executable-jar

I've the source for a java tool on my drive. I've built the tool successfully and I can run it with this command:

```
java -cp '<paths to jars>' <fully qualified class name> <arguments>
```

And it works correctly. But if I copy the jars specified in this command to `~/.local/jars` (which is in my CLASSPATH) and try to execute this command:

```
java <fully qualified class name> <arguments>
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
        at org.objectweb.asm.util.TraceClassVisitor.<init>(TraceClassVisitor.java:121)
        at org.objectweb.asm.util.Printer.main(Printer.java:1200)
        at org.objectweb.asm.util.ASMifier.main(ASMifier.java:134)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try using just the class name instead of fully qualified class name after you add classes to folder which is in CLASSPATH.

Comment: @madcobra I'm getting a `could not find class` error.

Comment: If a class is in CLASSPATH you shouldnt get that error. Can you try using a bat file to set CLASSPATH and run your java class as i have shown here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640828/specifying-java-classpath-from-cli-in-different-forms/49640941#49640941

Comment: @madcobra I don't get this error if I use the fully qualified class name.

Comment: Is `ASMifier` the class you’re trying to run?

Comment: @VGR yes it is.

Comment: What version of ASM are you using?

Comment: @VGR version 6.1

Comment: @VGR I'm getting the same error with asm 6.0 jars. ASMifier works fine with the official jar downloads.

Comment: That implies you are getting the error when using versions which are not official jar downloads.  Where are you getting those versions from?

Comment: I got the sources from `https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm`. And the jars built from these sources work fine if I specify the paths to their locations in the build directory, sorry for the confusion there. They give an illegal argument exception if I move them to a directory in my `CLASSPATH`.  The site also has links to download already built jars, which work fine no matter where I place them.